# ADFS get all roles for a Logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs

i am using this sample application provided in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753987%28WS.10%29.aspx
to play around with ADFS claim aware application.
my question is how can i get all the roles that the user is in using ADFS, the code above only has an example to check for the roles using  User.IsInRole(role).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [How to: Access Claims in an ASP.NET Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517271.aspx)

**Edit**: To answer the comment for WIF:

For supported Operating Systems: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2

- Microsoft® Internet Information Services (IIS) 7.0
- Microsoft® .NET Framework 3.5

For supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2

- Microsoft® Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0
- Microsoft® .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: is this only supported in ,net 3.0 and above, i am using .net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

For a full listing you could look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx)
and I would also point you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531991/how-do-i-get-other-claims-of-the-user-using-adfs) .

Comment: with the example i have technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753987%28WS.10%29.aspx if i add the code above i get error with CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IClaimsPrincipal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) what refrence do i need to add for this to work – Natasha Thapa 25 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

```
IClaimsPrincipal principal = (IClaimsPrincipal)this.Context.User;
IClaimsIdentity identity = principal.Identites[0];

var roles = identity.Claims
                .Where( c => c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Role )
                .Select( c => c.Value );
```

Comment: with the example i have http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753987%28WS.10%29.aspx 
if i add the code above i get error with 
 CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IClaimsPrincipal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
what refrence do i need to add for this to work

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4451 the dll names are System.IdentityModel and Microsoft.IdentityModel

Comment: @NatashaThapa: If you're using .NET 4.5, IClaimsPrincipal and IClaimsIdentity have been superseded by ClaimsPrincipal and ClaimsIdentity.